# Formula for Calculating consecutive cells with like values with a variable range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to come up with a formula that sums a variable range that is determined by a change in the text values of another column. I'm making a calculator that tells me when I have categorized my total deposit. Here's an example:

[image]

I'm listing a paycheck into a check book log, and I separate the money into different categories. I want the calculation in F5 to only sum the total of the cells in Column E that have a continuous run of the description "Check Deposit" in Column C. As soon as a cell in Column C changes to something else, no matter if it is 5 rows or 15 rows down, I want the calculation to stop there.

So, in this example, F5 would be `=F4-SUMIF(C4:C7,C4,E4:E7)`.  But I need C4:C7 and E4:E7 to change automatically if the description "Check Deposit" in Column C goes down even further the next time I use it.

I hope that makes sense. I know there's a way using VBA code, but I would like to find an equation to do this, if possible.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what your rules are. Can you edit your question to clarify? Do you want each cell in column F to be zero if the the earlier row in column C is **not** "Check deposit", and otherwise it should be the sum of all the values in column E from that row until the first row that doesn't have "Check Deposit" in column C? If so, the simplest solution may involve adding column(s) that provide the intermediate data for that calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about what you're trying to do, the following formula in  F5 might solve your problem.

```
=F$4-(E$4+SUM((C$4:C$20=C$4)*(C$4:C$20=C$3:C$19)*(E$4:E$20)))
```

This is an array formula, so it must be entered with CTRL-Shift Enter rather than just Enter.  If entered correctly, Excel will surround the formula with curly brackets {} in the formula bar.

The way this works is to create an array of numbers containing the amounts in Column E that satisfy the conditions you're looking for.

The first part, `(C$4:C$20=C$4)`, is TRUE wherever the range C4:C20 equals "Check Deposit".  The second part, `(C$4:C$20=C$3:C$19)`, is TRUE wherever a cell in C4:C20 equals the cell above it.

Multiplying these two arrays of logical values is the equivalent of the AND() operation and also converts the TRUE/FALSE values to 1 or 0.  So the result of this multiplication is the array `{0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}`.  Now multiplying by `(E$4:E$20)`, the array of amounts in Column E, gives `{0;50;50;50;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}`

Next we sum these values and add back E$4. (It was missing from the result array  because C4 is not equal to the cell above it).  Finally, subtracting all of this from the total in F4 gives the final result.

[image]

Notes:

1. You can extend or contract the ranges to suit your needs.  This
   formula checks down to row 20.
2. You didn't make it clear whether there could be more continuous "Check Deposit" values after the first interruption.  If your table
   above had "Check Deposit" in C10, the value in E10 would be
   counted.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough. I actually have a large complex equation that I built that will blank out column F and add the "Check" and "Total" to column F as well. I am just stuck on this calculation to only extend to the first interruption in the consecutive "Check Deposit" cells in column C. The way it works is, the next time "Check Deposit" shows up in column C after the interruption in the consecutive cells, another Check total calculator box will pop up in the F column again. I failed to show that in my example. I'll try your formula and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: That's good, I think. If the calculation is triggered by the first "Check Deposit" after the interruption, then there will never be *two* consecutive "Check Deposit" rows after the interruption, and this formula should work correctly.

Comment: I just had a thought, can I insert that formula inside another formula and submit the entire thing by Control+Shift+ENTER?

Comment: Yes, or you could put it somewhere else and have your combined formula just refer to the cell that holds the result.  That might be easier.

Comment: Well, now it looks like I have a new problem. It seems that when I have a gap in the consecutive cells, the formula will continue to calculate the second number in the next group of cells that start with "Check Deposit".

Comment: I really think I need something that will do a count and whatever that count totals to be at the break of the consecutive "Check Deposit" cells is what I need the formula to read. Since this is an ongoing log I want the calculation to show up and work for each group of "Check Deposit"(s) that show up in the log and only calculate each group, whether it takes up 1, 3, or 35 rows. Is there a way to do that without macros and using a LOOP function?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula worked perfectly, Blackwood.

=F$4-(E$4+SUM((C$4:C$20=C$4)*(C$4:C$20=C$3:C$19)*(E$4:E$20)))

I just inserted it into the proper place of my existing formula and it does exactly what I need. Thank you so much for your time and help. I've been racking my brain for days on this. I don't know why, but I just have the hardest time getting my brain around arrays.

Thanks again!